# Decompose Relation R(ABCDE) in 2nf and 3nf

Tags: normalization, dbms

Given relation R(ABCDE) with functional dependencies

A->C
B->D
AB->E
Given: AB is the primary key.

I know that this relation is in 1NF because of partial dependencies A->C and B->D

Now how I decompose it to get 2NF or better form.
My concepts are weak , so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The following two FD's violate 2NF:

```
A->C
B->D
```

We can create new relationships based upon those FD's: `(AC;A->C), (BD;B->D), (ABE;AB->E)`.  This set of relationships now satisfies 2NF (and also 3NF and BCNF).